# Return Value From function in controller to Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am passing a value from a page with ng-click to a function in a controller. This is successful, I am able to print the value to the console from the function. I am unable to access this value outside of the function, if I try to print outside of the function I get nothing. Specifically I want to display the value on another page. I am a beginner to ionic/angularjs, any help would be appreciated.

My code:

HTML

```
<a href="" ng-click="viewStory({{story.articleId}})">
```

Controller

```
.controller('NewsDisplayCtrl', function($scope, Articles) {  

    articleId = " ";
    text = " ";


    $scope.viewStory = (function(articleId){
    console.log("This is the passed in parameter " + articleId); 
        text = articleId;
    });

});
```

Next Page

```
<div ng-controller="NewsDisplayCtrl">      

    <h3>By: {{text}}</h3>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to $broadcast use the $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('broadcast', { foo: {} });
```

And then receive them:

```
$scope.$on('broadcast', function(event, args) {

    var foo = args.foo;
    // Your Codes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `{{}}` expression braces:

```
<a href="" ng-click="viewStory(story.articleId)">
```

Parameters passed to functions in `ng-` directives are evaluated as scope variables already

To share with another controller in another view you will need a service to share data and methods with

Comment: Thank you for the response, but it is sharing the value that I am having trouble with. You are right it works without the expression braces but it was already passing the value to the controller. If you could provide more help with sharing the value i would appreciate it, i have attempted to use a service but it has not worked.

Comment: sharing data is done with a service. There are lots of tutorials around on how to set it up